# Are the any open-source licenses which are incompatible with a C# winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, open-source, licensing

I'm open sourcing my app, which was built in C# using Windows Forms.

Are there any licensing issues I should be aware of? In particular, are there any open-source licenses that I'm prevented from using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: Hi @JasonMArcher. That's fine, but could it be migrated rather than close? I asked it before Programmers was launched and I don't think it's problematic as a question per se.

Comment: @TomWright See the [recent meta burnination effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) about legal and licensing tags. Also, even if licensing questions were on topic, this question is too broad. "Are there any..." is always suspect.

Comment: @durron597 Very well. I will submit to the wisdom of the meta mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. Open-source licenses control the rights to code that you wrote; it doesn't necessarily require that the underlying platform or framework be open-source.

Comment: You do need to check the licenses of any third-party libraries you use, though.

Comment: This was really what I was worried about. As long as the Winforms components aren't considered a 3rd party library, I'll be OK.